# Trigger phone call (tel or sip) using Action.OpenUrl in Adaptive Card in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, action-button

I am working on an adaptive card that is posted to users in Teams using Power Automate. The final thing I would like to add to the adaptive card, is a action button, that the user can click to call a person.

I have tried using both tel and sip in the URL. However nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Is this a limitation of Teams - or am I just doing it wrong?

```
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "Call Matt",
        "url": "tel:+4599999999",
        "id": "callMeId"
    }
]
```

[Adaptive Card Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f37nu.png)

BR,
Niels

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Microsoft Teams as default Apps for Tel Protocol.
[image]

You can try putting following in browser: +46890510
it will navigate you to the Microsoft Teams
[image]

it will open one pop up for Teams asking to call or not

Comment: Teams is already set as the default app for tel protocol - and it works fine in the browser or from an email etc.

However, I can't get it working from an adaptive card in Teams using a Action button.

Comment: Let me check this for Flow Bot or Adaptive Card Action button